# How to model postcode based search in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have 1.7 million uk postcodes using which I would like to do a search based on postcode to return list of nearest things. This will be a progressive list i.e.  start with nearest and as we scroll down it will return successive nearest things. For e.g. start showing things within 1/4 mile and we scroll down it extends to 1/2, 3/4, 1,2,3..N.

Is it a right approach to create relationship from a node to its nearest node that is within 1/4 mile and each of those nodes will in turn have relationship to its nearest nodes within 1/4 mile and so on?

Are there any other alternative modelling approach?

I played around with MongoDb and it is pretty fast in returning the nearest postcodes from a postcode within x radius.  However, I would like to use Neo4j as my entities/nodes have many other connected things (one of them is distance between them).

Comment: You should probably take a look at Neo4j Spatial :https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it also depends what you model as nodes, would you model the post-code areas?

Do you have information about their relationships and distances to each other? In general you can just model them as neighbours with the distance of their centers on the relationships, then the drilldown is an easy expansion of the neigbourhood query.

```
MATCH (pc:PostCode {code:"SE1 0NZ"})-[rels:NEIGHBOUR*..5]->(other:PostCode)
WHERE reduce(dist=0, r in rels | dist + r.dist) < 0.5
RETURN distinct other
LIMIT 15
```